# Entity Manager is always null in RestfulwebSerivces using JPA

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I am building a Restful web services using entity classes. I have written my code and it was working very well. But when I try to check this web services again, my webservice was not responding. And then I tried to debug it and found that my entity  manager instance is always null when the service gets deployed. I haven't change anything in persistent.xml. Below is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WebServerPrjPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>org.dicprj.ws</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am also pasting here  my code for the service:

```
package service;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import database.entity.Bordercountries;
import database.entity.Coordinates;
import database.entity.Countries;
import database.entity.Fullcountries;
import database.entity.Gdp;
import database.entity.Hdi;
import database.entity.Landarea;
import database.entity.Populations;
import database.entity.Uncode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author Manish
 */
@Stateless
@Path("generic")
public class countriesInfo {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebServerPrjPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of countriesInfo
     */
    public countriesInfo() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of database.entity.countriesInfo
     *
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getXml() {
        //TODO return proper representation object
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of countriesInfo
     *
     * @param content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void putXml(String content) {
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("countryinfo/{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public countryXML getCountryInfo(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        countryXML emptyOb = new countryXML();
        if (id == "") {
            return emptyOb;
        }
        String codeISO3 = GetISO3FrmCountryName(id);
        if (codeISO3 == "") {
            return emptyOb;
        }

        return GetXMLFromISO3(codeISO3);
    }
    @GET
    @Path("orderBy/{criteria}/{order}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public List<countryXML> GetConutryInfoByCriteria(@PathParam("criteria") String criteria, @PathParam("order")int ascending){
        boolean bAsc= true;
        if(ascending==0){
            bAsc = false;
        }
        if(criteria.equalsIgnoreCase("population")){
            return GetSortedCountryOnPoputaltion(bAsc);
        }else if(criteria.equalsIgnoreCase("gdp")){
            return GetSortedCountryOnGDP(bAsc);
        }else if(criteria.equalsIgnoreCase("landarea")){
            return GetSortedCountryOnLandArea(bAsc);
        }else if(criteria.equalsIgnoreCase("hdi")){
            return GetSortedCountryOnHDI(bAsc);
        }else{
            List<countryXML>list = new ArrayList<countryXML>();
            countryXML emptyOb = new countryXML();
            list.add(emptyOb);
            return list;
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("checkborder/{country1}/{country2}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String CheckBorderCountries(@PathParam("country1") String con1, @PathParam("country2") String con2) {
        if (AreBorderCountries(con1, con2)) {
            return "Both are border Countries";
        } else {
            return "Countries are not border countries";
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("frompos/{lat}/{lon}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public countryXML GetCountryFrmPosition(@PathParam("lat") double latitude, @PathParam("lon") double longitude) {
        String codeIso3 = GetISO3FrmCoOrdinates(latitude, longitude);
        return GetXMLFromISO3(codeIso3);
    }
    private String GetISO3FrmCountryName(String name) {
//        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Countries.findByNameListEN", Countries.class).setParameter("nameListEN", name);
//        Countries countryOb = (Countries) q.getSingleResult();
//        return countryOb.getCodeISO3();
        //First get code corresponding to the country name from fullCountryTable as user gives smaal names and counntry table has big names
        try {
            javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Fullcountries.findByCountryName", Fullcountries.class).setParameter("countryName", name);
            Fullcountries FullcountryOb1 = (Fullcountries) q.getSingleResult();
            return FullcountryOb1.getIsoAlpha3();
        }catch (NoResultException E) {
            System.out.println("There are no results from the query in Function GetISO3FrmCountryName" + E);
            return "";
        }

    }

    private boolean AreBorderCountries(String nameEn1, String nameEn2) {
        //First get code corresponding to the country name from fullCountryTable as user gives smaal names and counntry table has big names
        try {
            javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Fullcountries.findByCountryName", Fullcountries.class).setParameter("countryName", nameEn1);
            Fullcountries FullcountryOb1 = (Fullcountries) q.getSingleResult();

            q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Fullcountries.findByCountryName", Fullcountries.class).setParameter("countryName", nameEn2);
            Fullcountries FullcountryOb2 = (Fullcountries) q.getSingleResult();

            q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Bordercountries.findByNameListEN", Bordercountries.class).setParameter("nameListEN", nameEn1);
            List<Bordercountries> borderCountryOb1 = q.getResultList();
            Iterator<Bordercountries> iter = borderCountryOb1.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Bordercountries inBorderTable = (Bordercountries) iter.next();
                if (inBorderTable.getCodeISO3().equalsIgnoreCase(FullcountryOb2.getIsoAlpha3())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        } catch (NoResultException E) {
            System.out.println("There are no results from the query in Function AreBorderCountries" + E);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private String GetISO3FrmCoOrdinates(double lat, double lon) {
        try {
            javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
            javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<Coordinates> cq = cb.createQuery(Coordinates.class);
            javax.persistence.criteria.Root<Coordinates> mRoot = cq.from(Coordinates.class);
            javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate pValid1 = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(mRoot.<Double>get("hasMinLongitude"), lon);
            javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate pValid2 = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(mRoot.<Double>get("hasMaxLongitude"), lon);
            javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate pValid3 = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(mRoot.<Double>get("hasMinLatitude"), lat);
            javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate pValid4 = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(mRoot.<Double>get("hasMaxLatitude"), lat);
            javax.persistence.Query finalQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq.select(mRoot).where(cb.and(pValid1, pValid2, pValid3, pValid4)));
            finalQuery.setMaxResults(1);
            Coordinates ob = (Coordinates) finalQuery.getSingleResult();
            return ob.getCodeISO3();
        } catch (NoResultException E) {
            System.out.println("There are no results from the query in FUnction GetISO3FrmCoOrdinates" + E);
            return "";
        }
    }

    private countryXML GetXMLFromISO3(String iso3Code) {
        try {
            javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Uncode.findByCodeISO3", Uncode.class).setParameter("codeISO3", iso3Code);
            Uncode unCodeOb = (Uncode) q.getSingleResult();

            q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Fullcountries.findByIsoAlpha3", Fullcountries.class).setParameter("isoAlpha3", iso3Code);
            Fullcountries fullCountryInfoOb = (Fullcountries) q.getSingleResult();

            q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Populations.findByCodeISO3", Populations.class).setParameter("codeISO3", iso3Code);
            Populations populationOb = (Populations) q.getSingleResult();

            q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Gdp.findByCodeISO3", Gdp.class).setParameter("codeISO3", iso3Code);
            Gdp gdpOb = (Gdp) q.getSingleResult();

            q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Landarea.findByCodeISO3", Landarea.class).setParameter("codeISO3", iso3Code);
            Landarea landArea = (Landarea) q.getSingleResult();

            q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Hdi.findByCodeISO3", Hdi.class).setParameter("codeISO3", iso3Code);
            Hdi hdiOb = (Hdi) q.getSingleResult();

            countryXML xmlOb = new countryXML();
            xmlOb = xmlOb.SetUnCode(unCodeOb.getCodeUN().toString()).SetNameEn(fullCountryInfoOb.getCountryName()).SetCapitalName(fullCountryInfoOb.getCapital()).SetPopulation(populationOb.getPopulationTotal().toString());
            xmlOb.SetGDP(gdpOb.getGDPTotalInCurrentPrices().toString()).SetLandArea(landArea.getLandAreaTotal().toString()).SetHDI(hdiOb.getTotal().toString());
            return xmlOb;
        } catch (NoResultException E) {
            System.out.println("There are no results from the query in FUnction GetXMLFromISO3" + E);
            countryXML emptyOb = new countryXML();
            return emptyOb;
        }
    }

    private List<countryXML> GetSortedCountryOnPoputaltion(boolean asc) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<Populations> cq = cb.createQuery(Populations.class);
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<Populations> mRoot = cq.from(Populations.class);
        if (asc) {
            cq = cq.select(mRoot).orderBy(cb.asc(mRoot.<Double>get("populationTotal")));
        } else {
            cq = cq.select(mRoot).orderBy(cb.desc(mRoot.<Double>get("populationTotal")));
        }
        javax.persistence.Query finalQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        finalQuery.setMaxResults(10);
        List<Populations> list = finalQuery.getResultList();
        List<countryXML>listResult = new ArrayList<countryXML>();
        Iterator<Populations>iter = list.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Populations rowOb = iter.next();
            listResult.add(GetXMLFromISO3(rowOb.getCodeISO3()));
        }
        return listResult;
    }
      private List<countryXML> GetSortedCountryOnGDP(boolean asc) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<Gdp> cq = cb.createQuery(Gdp.class);
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<Gdp> mRoot = cq.from(Gdp.class);
        if (asc) {
            cq = cq.select(mRoot).orderBy(cb.asc(mRoot.<Double>get("GDPTotalInCurrentPrices")));
        } else {
            cq = cq.select(mRoot).orderBy(cb.desc(mRoot.<Double>get("GDPTotalInCurrentPrices")));
        }
        javax.persistence.Query finalQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        finalQuery.setMaxResults(10);
        List<Gdp> list = finalQuery.getResultList();
        List<countryXML>listResult = new ArrayList<countryXML>();
        Iterator<Gdp>iter = list.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Gdp rowOb = iter.next();
            listResult.add(GetXMLFromISO3(rowOb.getCodeISO3()));
        }
        return listResult;
    }
     private List<countryXML> GetSortedCountryOnLandArea(boolean asc) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<Landarea> cq = cb.createQuery(Landarea.class);
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<Landarea> mRoot = cq.from(Landarea.class);
        if (asc) {
            cq = cq.select(mRoot).orderBy(cb.asc(mRoot.<Double>get("landAreaTotal")));
        } else {
            cq = cq.select(mRoot).orderBy(cb.desc(mRoot.<Double>get("landAreaTotal")));
        }
        javax.persistence.Query finalQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        finalQuery.setMaxResults(10);
        List<Landarea> list = finalQuery.getResultList();
        List<countryXML> listResult = new ArrayList<countryXML>();
        Iterator<Landarea> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Landarea rowOb = iter.next();
            listResult.add(GetXMLFromISO3(rowOb.getCodeISO3()));
        }
        return listResult;
    }
    private List<countryXML> GetSortedCountryOnHDI(boolean asc) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<Hdi> cq = cb.createQuery(Hdi.class);
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<Hdi> mRoot = cq.from(Hdi.class);
        if (asc) {
            cq = cq.select(mRoot).orderBy(cb.asc(mRoot.<Double>get("Total")));
        } else {
            cq = cq.select(mRoot).orderBy(cb.desc(mRoot.<Double>get("Total")));
        }
        javax.persistence.Query finalQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        finalQuery.setMaxResults(10);
        List<Hdi> list = finalQuery.getResultList();
        List<countryXML> listResult = new ArrayList<countryXML>();
        Iterator<Hdi> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Hdi rowOb = iter.next();
            listResult.add(GetXMLFromISO3(rowOb.getCodeISO3()));
        }
        return listResult;
    }
}
```

And this is my glassfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_faodata_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="faodata"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="manish"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/faodata?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="org.dicprj.ws" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_faodata_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

Errors show by glasshfish server

```
INFO: file:/E:/Data/Study/Home/DIC_PROJ1/WebServer/WebServerPrj/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_WebServerPrjPU logout successful
INFO: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
INFO: file:/E:/Data/Study/Home/DIC_PROJ1/WebServer/WebServerPrj/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/_WebServerPrjPU login successful
WARNING: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@1c14aa61].
WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@1c14aa61] from index [0] 
WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@4d7f4bab] from index [1] 
INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB countriesInfo: [java:global/WebServerPrj/countriesInfo, java:global/WebServerPrj/countriesInfo!service.countriesInfo]
INFO: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig, at the servlet mapping, /webresources/*, with the Application class of the same name
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [WebServerPrj] at [/WebServerPrj]
INFO: WebServerPrj was successfully deployed in 409 milliseconds.
SEVERE: Error when configuring to use the EJB interceptor binding API. JAX-RS EJB support is disabled.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor183.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ejb.EJBComponentProviderFactoryInitilizer.initialize(EJBComponentProviderFactoryInitilizer.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:574)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:311)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:608)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1453)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.registerSystemInterceptor(BaseContainer.java:3386)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.InternalInterceptorBindingImpl.registerInterceptor(InternalInterceptorBindingImpl.java:100)
    ... 36 more

INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.11.1 03/31/2012 06:49 PM'
INFO: Instantiated the Application class org.netbeans.rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can anyone explain what might be wrong in the configuarion or in code?
Thanks  in advance.

Comment: What errors does your log show? Where is the definition of your datasource?

Comment: @Perception
I have added my server resource file above. In error it is throwing the null pointer exception whenever somemethod is accesed via em.

Comment: Thanks for adding the data source. Check your server log, right around the area displaying the startup messages, and look for Amy startup errors related to loading the persistence context.

Comment: @Perception
I am not able to see any error related to persistence context.I have attached the errors which my server windows is showing in above post..

Comment: @Perception
Now, when I closed my IDE and started the service, it is running fine without any change. I am really unable tounderstand what is happening?

Comment: Could be resource exhaustion, or a corrupted workspace. Not sure, its hard to diagnose IDE related problems without a log file. Sounds like the problem is solved for now though.

Comment: Yup problem is solved. One thing which I noticed that when my application was not working there were too many connection present to the database, these all connections were coming from the same application but on the different ports. So when I closed it, these all coonections were removed. This might be a possible reason.